# Voltar a página e atualizar os dados

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma tela que lista os meus produtos. Para cadastrar um novo produto, abro uma outra tela para inserir os dados e assim efetuar o cadastro, nesta mesma tela tenho um botão voltar, nele tenho o código `onClick="history.back()"`, porém quando volta para a lista dos produtos, aquele produto que eu acabei de cadastrar não lista, só lista quando faço uma nova pesquisa.
Tem alguma forma de voltar e atualizar a lista? Algo do tipo, `history.back() + location.reload()`.

Comment: Já que está a trabalhar com PHP,  por que não tenta criar um header("Location: suaURL"). Assim, o codigo ira retorná-lo automaticamente para a página anterior.

Comment: No botão voltar?

Comment: O botão para voltar é necessário? Da forma com que indiquei, após o INSERT em PHP, seria redirecionado automaticamente.

Comment: Porém faço o insert com ajax

Comment: Alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Poderia colocar um pouco de código (o da lista de produtos) para podermos *visualizar* melhor, ver como é pupulada esta lista!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure substituir o método **history.back()** por **location.replace('sua_pagina_anterior.php')**.

Se isso não resolver é porque a lógica da página inicial não está adequada ou o script acionado por AJAX não está fazendo a inserção.
(porque você não postou o código e apenas podemos supor).

Se o problema persistir, não sinta-se constangido em perguntar +

Answer (score 3):

Entrei a solução em outro fórum, seguem o [link](http://goo.gl/4qiOYK)

Solução

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

(function() {
   if( window.localStorage ) {

      if( !localStorage.getItem( 'firstLoad' ) ) {
         localStorage[ 'firstLoad' ] = true;
         window.location.reload();

      } else {
         localStorage.removeItem( 'firstLoad' );
      }
   }
})();
```